# Users can still access MS Exchange emails after disabling user account

Tags: exchange-server, user-accounts

I have an on premise Exchange 2016 Server and I found that after disabling a users account the user is still able to send and receive emails from his / her mobile device hours after the account has been disabled. Is that a what to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with ActiveSync.  If you disable the users account you should remove their device from the ActiveSync to their mailbox.  The ActiveSync can keep a connection open for hours before re-authenticating.

Below are two links describing what you are experiencing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2612821/eas-devices-still-sync-after-an-account-is-disabled-or-a-password-is-c

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3406.exchange-best-practices-for-untrusted-mailbox-users.aspx